# Send informations via Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying to make use of cloud messaging for my Android app. The server is sending messages via PHP using `php-curl`.

The problem is that the server's response is always:

> 401: Unauthorized

I use the WebAPI Access key from the Firebase Console for my App, so this is definitively the right one. Below is the code I use to send the data:

```
<?php

$fields = array(
    'to' => "<MY-RECIPIENT-TOKEN>",
    'notification' => array(
        'body' => 'Test message :)',
        'title' => 'Test',
        'icon' => 'myicon',
        'sound' => 'mySound'
    )
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization:key=<MY AUTH KEY IS HERE>',
    'Content-Type:application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

The `MY-RECIPIENT-TOKEN` is received from the App and the `MY AUTH KEY IS HERE` is the key from the Firebase Console.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The Problem is not in the code, the code is fine. If someone stumbles upon this: There are 2 keys in your FCM Console. When you go to your Project Settings you will find the Web-API-Key. This is **not** the key you are looking for! You need to go to Settings -> Cloud Messaging. There you will see a much longer Server key. **THIS** is the key you want to use!